# Custom delegate issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, automatic-ref-counting, weak

I'm working with a custom delegate and protocol functionality.

I implemented my class like follows:

```
@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)update;

@end

@interface MyHandlerClass : NSObject
{
    id <MyDelegate>delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyDelegate>delegate;

@end
```

My implementation class looks like:

```
@implementation MyHandlerClass
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
- (void)updateRequired: (id)sender
{
    if(delegate)
    {
        [delegate update];
    }
}
@end
```

And from another class I'm setting it like:

```
[sharedManager setDelegate:self];
```

But when the `updateRequired` is triggered it is showing as `nil`.

Then I added a setter method like:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<MyDelegate>)aDelegate
{
   delegate = aDelegate;
}
```

Everything works fine !!!

Then I changed the `updateRequired` method (without custom setter) like:

```
- (void)updateRequired: (id)sender
    {
        if(_delegate)
        {
            [_delegate update];
        }
    }
```

It is also working fine !!!

I couldn't find why it is not worked for the first case and why it is worked for the other two cases ?

Please help me to find the issue, Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `self.delegate` instead of just `delegate` and then check the same case. You may not need `id <MyDelegate>delegate;` and `@synthesize delegate = _delegate;` together. Ideally, you can remove both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have inadvertently declared one ivar called `delegate`

```
  id <MyDelegate>delegate;
```

and another ivar called `_delegate`

```
  @synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

Some suggestions...

- don't declare the iVar separately from your @property declaration
- don't @synthesize, since XCode 4.4 you don't have to. The compiler will autosynthesize and autocreate an iVar with leading underscore
- always refer to you ivar via it's property, inside and outside of your class. Only exceptions are in init, dealloc and inside custom setters and getters.

So this is how your code should look

```
    @protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>

    @required
    - (void)update;
    @end

    @interface MyHandlerClass : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyDelegate>delegate;
    @end

    @implementation MyHandlerClass

    - (void)updateRequired: (id)sender
    {
        if(self.delegate)
        {
            [self.delegate update];
        }
    }
    @end
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use

```
if(delegate)
```

You are pointing to the instance variable "delegate".

However, when you use

```
[sharedManager setDelegate:self]
```

This is setting the instance variable "_delegate" to "self".

Try this:

```
if (self.delegate) {
    [self.delegate update];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To access your delegate property in the updateRequired method, you can do it by either using the private variable **_delegate** or by using **self.delegate**. Because when you synthesize using delegate =  _delegate, setters and getters are automatically created.

This line tells the compiler to create a setter and getter for delegate, and that they should use the ivar called _delegate. Without the = _delegate part, the compiler would assume that the property and ivar have the same name.